# Create an API directly from a data source

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I need to create my own REST API.
I just saw strongloop and loopback and I thought it will be perfect for my project.

In fact, I was able to get mysql connected using strongloop. However, I had to create something called a "model" and I did it. But, it was like creating a new model from scratch and use it for persisting on the Datasource.

Instead, what I was looking for, is to get a REST API directly from my model on the DB.
I mean taking the models from each table on the DB and then set them up as web services.

Is that possible?

I am newbie on these technologies, although I think it is an interesting question.

Thanks

Comment: Great question, by the way, I hope other people upvote / comment on this!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of a Node tool to do what you're asking, but in other languages / databases you have some choices!

The only one I'm really familiar with is postgrest.

[postgrest](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest): You import your data into a Postgres database (similar to MySQL), and it generates a REST API on top of your tables instantly. Bam. Done. I've used this and it was amazingly awesome. You can also deploy it directly on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: It sounds good, although it means that I would have to do a migration changing more than one functionality that are currently pointing to the db.
I have never done before to PostgreSQL, it may be not to hard to get done.
However, I suppose a lot of o people are moving to Nodejs from PHP
(area in which MySQL is the most used, not sure but I think) so there should be a way to do that on MySQL as well.
Still if it can be a nice solution, how will you connect this with strongloop?
Thanks, I appreciate your answer and I'll keep in mind like a good option if I am not able do that with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

StrongLoop actually has a ["discovery" tool](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Discovering+models+from+relational+databases) for just this purpose! Read up on that page, but here's the basic code to do it. Just drop this code in a file inside `/server/boot/` (the docs are wrong on that, it must be in the directory I mention). Of course, you'll need to tailor it for your use case:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var ds = loopback.createDataSource('mysql', {
  "host": "yourhost",
  "port": 1234,
  "database": "foobar",
  "username": "someuser",
  "password": "somepass"
});

// Discover and build models from a given table
ds.discoverAndBuildModels('PERSON', {visited: {}, associations: true},
function (err, models) {
  // Now we have a list of models keyed by the model name
  // You only need the rest of this if wanted to inspect what came in...

  // For example, you could find the first record from the table
  // and verify info or something.
  models.Person.findOne({}, function (err, person) {
    if(err) {
      // handle this if need be...
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    // Some code using `person`

  });
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was supposing "discovery tool" was to find out pattern, cluster or whatever else thing into the data. But following 
the recomendation of @jakarella I went with more depth.

It was even easier than that, because you can do everything via StrongLoop Arc (GUI). I always prefer cli
but to have a general look of it, sometimes is better to start with the GUI if you don't have too much idea about the subject.

Anyway,
first of all you would need to connect your datasource before (installing previously the driver). 
After that, through StrongLoop Arc you can do "discover the models" choosing your tables (taking care of run Arc and restarting every time 
you get a new model) and that's it, you get an API over your Datasource
(for testing go to the explorer).

I described before generally the main tasks but if anyone needs more detail pls let me know. Hope this helps to anyone else who is looking to do 
something similar

thanks guys for the interest.